# Grep in vim does not show findings with option exclude

Tags: python, vim, grep

In my ~/.vimrc, I defined following command:

```
command! -nargs=+ Mygrep execute 'grep -I -i -r -n --exclude=*.{py~,pyc} . -e <args>'
```

If for example no .pyc file is located in the directory searched by grep, the only message printed is:

```
"zsh:1: no matches found: --exclude=*.py~"
```

and matching results in .py files are not shown!

Defining the command without option exclude
(`command! -nargs=+ Mygrep execute 'grep -I -i -r -n . -e <args>'`) works as expected.

Why does the exclude variant does not work properly?

Comment: syntax is `--exclude=`...

Comment: Thanks! But despite correcting the typo  still the same message...

Comment: hmm... I don't know about the vim syntax in this case... does the command work as is from zsh command line? also, does `--exclude=*.py~` or `--exclude=*.pyc` alone work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable solution:

In my .vimrc (copied from a colleague) I changed from `zsh` to `bash`:

```
set shell=/path/to/bash
```

Thank you for your hints!